# Preg_replace_callback storing in array

Tags: php, arrays, regex, global

I'm looking to store every match found using preg_replace_callback in an array which is to be used at a later point. This is what I have so far and I can't work out what is wrong, currently it is storing the last match found, in both $match[0] and $match[3].

What I am attempting to achieve overall is to replace every match with a hyperlinked number, then print the full text below it. Each number is to be linked to its corresponding text.

```
            global $match;
            $match = array();
            $pattern = $regex;
                $body = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
                    static $count = 0;
                    $count ++;
                    $match = $matches;
                    return "<a href=\"#ref $count\">$count</a>"; 
                }, $body);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the `global` statement inside the function. You also need to push a new element onto the `$match` array, not overwrite it. And I doubt you want a space between `#ref` and `$count` in the `href` attribute.

```
$match = array();
$pattern = $regex;
$body = preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches){
    global $match;
    static $count = 0;
    $count ++;
    $match[] = $matches;
    return "<a href=\"#ref$count\">$count</a>"; 
}, $body);
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to change anything, print_r($match) still outputs the same as I mentioned originally. For reference i am calling print_r just after the code above.

Comment: You were overwriting `$match` instead of adding a new element.

Comment: Just saw that you added [] to $match, now it seems to be putting too much into the array.
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => match1 [1] => [2] => [3] => match1 )
This is the output for each match, how would I reduce this?

Comment: I just fixed this myself, I changed $matches; to $matches[0];
Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$matches` is an array where `$matches[0]` is the match for the entire regexp, `$matches[1]` is the match for the first capture group, and so on. If you don't want all the capture groups, push what you want, e.g. `$matches[0]` onto `$match`. It's not clear from the question exactly what you're trying to collect into `$match`. Surely you can take the basic structure of the answer and fit it to your actual needs.

Comment: I was looking for the entire regexp, wasn't sure why $matches had so much stored in it. Thanks for your assistance, I'll mark this as answered.